# Iterate through Swift array and change values

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, mapreduce

I need to change values of a Swift array.
My first try was to just iterate through but this does not work as I only get a copy of each element and the changes do not affect the origin array.
Goal is to have a unique "index" in each array element.

```
myArray = [["index": 0], ["index":0], ["index":0], ["index":0]]

counter = 0
for item in myArray {
  item["index"] = counter
  counter += 1
}
```

My next attempt was using map but I don't know how to set an increasing value. I could set the `$0["index"] = 1` but I need an increasing value.
In which way would this be possible using map?

```
myArray.map( { $0["index"] = ...? } )
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you show the code that you've used to create the array?

Comment: The array ist just a list of dictionaries that are not created in the code but loaded from a file and a value for the non existing key "index" has to be added for each dictionary

Comment: Please edit you're question with any additional information that would make your problem easy to understand and reproduce in a playground

Comment: Added myArray in the original code so it can be reproduced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple way and would like to share it.

The key is the definition of `myArray`. It would success if it's in this way:

```
 let myArray : [NSMutableDictionary] = [["firstDict":1, "otherKey":1], ["secondDict":2, "otherKey":1], ["lastDict":2, "otherKey":1]]

 myArray.enumerated().forEach{$0.element["index"] = $0.offset}

 print(myArray)






 [{
firstDict = 1;
index = 0;
otherKey = 1;
 }, {
index = 1;
otherKey = 1;
secondDict = 2;
}, {
index = 2;
lastDict = 2;
otherKey = 1;
}]
```

Answer (score 19):

The counter in a `for` loop is a constant. To make it mutable, you could use :

```
for var item in myArray { ... }
```

But that won't be helpful here since we'd be mutating `item` and not the elements in `myArray`.

You could mutate the elements in `myArray` this way :

```
var myArray = [["index": 0], ["index":0], ["index":0], ["index":0]]

var counter = 0

for i in myArray.indices {
    myArray[i]["index"] = counter
    counter += 1
}

print(myArray) //[["index": 0], ["index": 1], ["index": 2], ["index": 3]]
```

---

The `counter` variable is not needed here :

```
for i in myArray.indices {
    myArray[i]["index"] = i
}
```

---

A functional way of writing the above would be :

```
myArray.indices.forEach { myArray[$0]["index"] = $0 }
```

Comment: thanks for the functional way using forEach, not map

Answer (score 0):

How about a more functional approach by creating a brand new array to store the modified dictionaries:

```
let myArray = [["index": 0], ["index":0], ["index":0], ["index":0]]
let myNewArray = myArray.enumerated().map { index, _ in ["index": index] }
```